# Event object doesn't pass to script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-installable-triggers

We have a lot of google Form with related answers files. All spreadsheet files with answers contain a GScript which run by trigger "*On send form*"

But only one form stopped run this script. Answer write into spreadsheet
*correct*, but related script seems doesn't execute.

This script  receive object trigger event and send email with last row from
spreadsheet

```
function sendFormByEmail(e) {
     var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
     var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
     ....
     ....
     GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject,messageTxt,{'htmlBody':messageHTML,'name': 'HR-bot'});
}
```

So strange that we have **exactly** the same script in other spreadsheet and it works perfect!

Moreover if comment all this script and leave only row with **GmailApp.sendEmail** and send GoogleForm , answers write into spreadsheet correct but trigger "On send form" may not occurs and even that one row not execute

Thanks for help

P.S. How to debug this type of script that takes  [Event Object Argument](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) ?

Comment: Use console.log to check for values or for errors. Try also Chrome DevTools (Right click page -> Inspect) if any error logs are present. You may also check this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39068904/event-object-for-form-submit-on-google-apps-script-not-working) for additional insight as it tackles event objects on google forms.

Comment: Regarding how to debug scripts that require an event object, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas/16089067#16089067

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **Rubén** , i have use this approach [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas/16089067#16089067)

And that's my result:

```
  var dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var lastRow = data[data.length-1];
  var headers = data[0];

   for (var row=1; row < data.length; row++) {
    var e = {};
    e.values = data[row].filter(Boolean);  
    e.range = dataRange.offset(row,0,1,data[0].length);
    e.namedValues = {};
    // Loop through headers to create namedValues object
    // NOTE: all namedValues are arrays.
    for (var col=0; col<headers.length; col++) {
      e.namedValues[headers[col]] = [data[row][col]];
    }
   }
```

**lastRow** variable contain value of lastRow and with Debug i found that all my code works perfect 
And accidentally i have recreated Answer file and deleted connection between form and answer file
Create new answer file and place into my code. And it works!

Summary: if you think that your answer file doesn't pass trigger event object or even doesn't run a .gs "On send form" - just clear answers from form and attach it to absolutely new answer file